# Can this function produce uncountable number of values?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Consider $f=\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k\chi_{A_k}$, where $a_k\in\mathbb{R}$ and $\chi_{A_k}$ is the indicator function on the set $A_k$.

My question is, can $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ possibly produce (as output) uncountably many values?

---

My attempt:

Clearly, if $A_k$ are disjoint, then $f$ can only produce countably many values, namely the $a_k$, and possibly 0.

What about in the general case, where $A_k$ may not be disjoint?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What if you consider binary representations of $x \in [0,1)$, i.e., $x=0.b_1b_2b_3...$.

Comment: @Michael Thanks for your suggestion. However, I don't really know how to use that fact here.

Comment: Just try playing around with the definition.  What does a binary representation mean?

Comment: Ah, your $f$ isn't well defined, was the sum may not converges for every $x$.

Comment: Your induction update is faulty.  By the same reasoning you can prove the false claim that the reals are countable because truncating the decimal expansion to $k$ digits leads to a countable set of possible values for all positive integers $k$.

Comment: @Michael Good point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a natural bijection between $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$. So for each $C \subseteq \mathbb{N}$, associate a unique $x_C \in \mathbb{R}$. Define $A_n = \{x_C : n \in C\}$ and let $a_n = 2^{-n}$.

The point is, we can choose $x$ so that we get any sum of powers of $2$ we want. Via binary representations, this has a natural correspondence with $[0,1]$, so we get uncountably many outputs, as desired.